# Convert delimited string to array and group using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, csv

I have a string that has a delimited format like this:

**orgname**: firstname lastname, firstname lastname;

(this can repeat with orgnames and variable number of names for each org)

Example:

```
**XXX University**: Martha Zander, Rick Anderson; **Albert School**: Nancy Vanderburg, Eric Towson, George Branson; **Hallowed Halls**: Jane Goodall, Ann Crabtree, Rick Grey, Tammy Hudson;
```

The resultant string needs to be grouped and sorted by orgname and then lastname like this:

```
**Albert School**: George Branson, Eric Towson, Nancy Vanderburg; 
**Hallowed Halls**: Ann Crabtree, Jane Goodall, Rick Grey, Tammy Hudson;
**XXX University**: Rick Anderson, Martha Zander;
```

I have gotten this far:

```
string[][] splitThis = staff.Split(';').Select(s => s.Split(':')).ToArray();
```

This gives me an array split up by orgname and then I am stuck after this.

I know I need a multidimensional array with orname, firstname, lastname but I don't know how to populate, group and sort it to get the proper result.

Comment: Why not use a sorted dictionary ?

Comment: Is there any chance that you will have a person that doesn't have exactly two parts to their name?  Like `Mary Jane Watson` or `Dale Earnhardt Jr.`?

Comment: How do you *define* lastname. You have people with multiple first names, or with multiple last names. Like "William Of Baskeville", "Vlad the Impaler" and "Marie Rose Foo".

Comment: Why do you need a multidimensional array?  This seems like a perfect time to define classes (like `Person` and `Organization`).

Comment: Unfortunately the data comes to us in this format by the client and was all hand-entered into one field of a database (***sigh***).  We were told to sort it as best as possible for display.  Therefore it _would_ be possible to have multiple first or last names but I don't think there would be a way to determine and adjust for this. @ryanyuyu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var input =
    @"**Albert School**: George Branson, Eric Towson, Nancy Vanderburg; 
     **Hallowed Halls**: Ann Crabtree, Jane Goodall, Rick Grey, Tammy Hudson;
     **XXX University**: Rick Anderson, Martha Zander;";

    var universities = input
                      .Split(';')
                      .Select(ParseUniversity)
                      .ToArray();
}

public static University ParseUniversity(string line)
{
    var fields = line
                .Split(',',':')
                .Select(f=>f.Trim('*','\n','\r', '\t' ,' '))  // remove trailing crap
                .ToArray();

    var universityName = fields.First();

    var persons = fields
                 .Skip(1)  // skip university field
                 .Select(ParsePerson)
                 .ToArray();

    return new University {Name = universityName, Persons = persons};
}

public static Person ParsePerson(string field)
{
    var p = field.Split(' ');
    return new Person{FirstName = p.First(), LastName = p.Last()};
}

public class University
{
    public string   Name    {get;set;}
    public Person[] Persons {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName  {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: this is just what I needed!  The data is now organized perfectly. A million thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex here

```
string input = @"**XXX University**: Martha Zander, Rick Anderson; **Albert School**: Nancy Vanderburg, Eric Towson, George Branson; **Hallowed Halls**: Jane Goodall, Ann Crabtree, Rick Grey, Tammy Hudson;";
var dict = Regex.Matches(input, @"\*\*(.+?)\*\*: (.+?);")
           .Cast<Match>()
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value, x=>x.Groups[2].Value.Split(','));
```

`dict` would be (in json):

```
{
  "XXX University": [
    "Martha Zander",
    " Rick Anderson"
  ],
  "Albert School": [
    "Nancy Vanderburg",
    " Eric Towson",
    " George Branson"
  ],
  "Hallowed Halls": [
    "Jane Goodall",
    " Ann Crabtree",
    " Rick Grey",
    " Tammy Hudson"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @EZI, That helps get the data into parsed into json format but I need to get it sorted and grouped by org and then sorted by last name.  It's a good lesson for me how to use Dictionary and regex effectively.  I appreciate it!